# php smarty check form

Tags: php, smarty

I have a confuse in php smarty

this is my code and I wanna check the value when user submit before.

```
<script>
function check(){
    if(document.getElementById("delway").value = ""){
        window.alert('Please choose payment method');
    }
}
</script>


<form action="" method="post" name="form">
<input class="" type="radio" name="delway" value="1">Credit Card</span>
<input class="" type="radio" name="delway" value="2">Pick up</span>
<input class="" type="radio" name="delway" value="3">Google Pay</span>

<button type="submit" name="checkorder" value="1" onclick="check()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

but I dont know why it isn't check the form.

Comment: Because none of your elements have an ID of `delway`. They just have the name attribute specified - so it won't find anything

Answer (score 0):

### I am using google translate.

First, you don't have an id "delway".

Second, to check whether the radio is checked or not, we use the following structure:

```
let radioChecked = document.querySelector("input[name=delway]:checked")
if(radioChecked == null){
    //not checked
}
```

Third, when the button is clicked with type = "submit", the form will be submitted before js is executed.

To prevent that, the function should not be executed at the button. Instead, leave it in the onsubmit of the form.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return check()">
```

If the function check return false, the form will not be submitted and will alert the message.

Another thing is that when comparing the if statement, the == sign must be used

### Example

```
<script>
function check(){
    if(document.querySelector("input[name=delway]:checked") == null){
        window.alert('Please choose payment method');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>


<form action="" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return check()">
    <input class="" type="radio" name="delway" value="1">Credit Card</span>
    <input class="" type="radio" name="delway" value="2">Pick up</span>
    <input class="" type="radio" name="delway" value="3">Google Pay</span>

    <button type="submit" name="checkorder" value="1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: when I choose the payment then click submit, it still display "Please choose payment method.